# Plex Media Server won't start

Tags: 16.04, 32-bit, plex

Been trying to setup a plex server for the last 2 days. I initially had it up and running, but I rebooted, and now I can't get it start back up.

**Background:**

- Running 16.04 32bit
- Had installed and set up server once everything was working fine
- Rebooted machine
- Since reboot, have not been able to get server running

  - Ran `sudo dpkg -r plexmediaserver` and `sudo dpkg -P plexmediaserver`, then reinstalled, but this bares no effect on the error
- Also running sonarr and nzbget (I doubt that has any impact on the issue, but you never know)

Ran `sudo systemctl status plexmediaserver` and output is as follows:

```
    plexmediaserver.service - Plex Media Server for Linux
    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/plexmediaserver.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-11-20 21:47:11 EST; 44s ago
    Process: 5144 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/plexmediaserver "/usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Plex Media Server" (
    Process: 5140 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/test -d "${PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_APPLICATION_SUPPORT_DIR}" || /bin/mkdir -p "${
    Main PID: 5144 (code=exited, status=127)

    Nov 20 21:47:05 media-server systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Unit entered failed state.
    Nov 20 21:47:05 media-server systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    Nov 20 21:47:11 media-server systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
    Nov 20 21:47:11 media-server systemd[1]: Stopped Plex Media Server for Linux.
    Nov 20 21:47:11 media-server systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
    Nov 20 21:47:11 media-server systemd[1]: Failed to start Plex Media Server for Linux.
    Nov 20 21:47:44 media-server systemd[1]: Stopped Plex Media Server for Linux.
```

results of `journalctl -xe`

```
-- Subject: Unit plexmediaserver.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit plexmediaserver.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Nov 20 21:47:00 media-server sh[5132]: /bin/sh: 1: /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Plex Media Server: not found
Nov 20 21:47:00 media-server systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Nov 20 21:47:00 media-server systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 20 21:47:00 media-server systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 20 21:47:04 media-server sudo[5137]:    david : TTY=pts/7 ; PWD=/home/david/Downloads ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl status plexmediaserver
Nov 20 21:47:04 media-server sudo[5137]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 20 21:47:05 media-server systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 20 21:47:05 media-server systemd[1]: Stopped Plex Media Server for Linux.
-- Subject: Unit plexmediaserver.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit plexmediaserver.service has finished shutting down.
Nov 20 21:47:05 media-server systemd[1]: Starting Plex Media Server for Linux...
-- Subject: Unit plexmediaserver.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit plexmediaserver.service has begun starting up.
Nov 20 21:47:05 media-server systemd[1]: Started Plex Media Server for Linux.
-- Subject: Unit plexmediaserver.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit plexmediaserver.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Nov 20 21:47:05 media-server sh[5144]: /bin/sh: 1: /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Plex Media Server: not found
Nov 20 21:47:05 media-server systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Nov 20 21:47:05 media-server systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 20 21:47:05 media-server systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 20 21:47:10 media-server sudo[5137]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Nov 20 21:47:11 media-server systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 20 21:47:11 media-server systemd[1]: Stopped Plex Media Server for Linux.
-- Subject: Unit plexmediaserver.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit plexmediaserver.service has finished shutting down.
```

Comment: run `journalctl -xe` and lets see what the problem might be!

Comment: added to question because it was too long for comment

Comment: That was the right thing to have done, :), but it's incomplete some texts are missing!

Comment: sorry i'm a bit of a newbie to ubuntu, i think i've updated with what you expected

Comment: I think this is the same problem: https://forums.plex.tv/discussion/282507/failed-to-start-plex-media-server

Answer (score 0):

From the link provided by Michael Bay two steps to solve this:

1. Open a terminal and run:

   ```
   sudo locale-gen en_us.utf-8   #this is a comment:(or your appropriate locale)
   ```
2. The using `nano` text editor open the `lexmediaserver.service` file found in `/etc/systemd/system/` and make sure the locale is set:

   ```
   Environment=LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
   ```

Source:

https://forums.plex.tv/discussion/282507/failed-to-start-plex-media-server
        Environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Comment: Will try this after work today. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This does not appear to have worked. I also noticed that the exit code in the link is different. I'm getting 127, they're getting 134

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue when i first installed plex server manually, i did not worked for me too. Went through the forums, everyone recommended to set system locale and lang correctly, which i did while installing the ubuntu server.

i do not have the "correct answer" as i do not know what caused it and how to fix it, but i can tell you the workaround i used to get it working, it might help you as well

i used third party toolkit, i have never experienced a problem with it and IMHO it works good for newbie like me. You can try too, follow:

https://github.com/htpcBeginner/AtoMiC-ToolKit

**edit**: Give atomic toolkit a try, but by looking at your journalctl -xe results, you may not have the rw access for the path, do

```
ls -l
```

on the /usr/lib/plexmediaserver directory, you may not have set correct ownership, try changing owner ship with

```
sudo chown -R "user:group" <folder_name>
```

**OR** in your setup the path has a extra space, believe me that happens

Comment: will try the toolkit after work. Tried changing permissions & ownership last night, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: I tried atk, it looked very promising during the install, but it continues to fail on startup with the same error.

Comment: Alas ! can you report if you have your locale and lang setup correctly, see previous answers in the ports by other users

Comment: I had done that prior, but it bore no impact on the issue. I eventually just reformatted and it didnt happen after a fresh install